# Can web UIkit work in a Shadow DOM context?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs, getuikit

I'm using StencilJS and having difficulty getting a UIkit widget to work ([the slider](https://getuikit.com/docs/slider), if it matters).  UIkit has had no trouble working in other Stencil components, but this is the first time I've tried it on a component that is a Shadow Node.

My first assumption was that the CSS wasn't getting applied correctly because of the Shadow barrier, but after directly importing the UIkit styles into the Stencil component (and seeing them applied in dev tools), it seemed more like the JS was not initializing correctly.  Here is some failing markup sourced from the UIkit site with a `ref` from Stencil, and a JS init call.

```html
<!-- mode: open -->
<web-component-shadow-root>
  <div uk-slider ref={el => this.sliderEl = el}>
    <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-4">
      <li>
        <img src="//path/to/img.png" />
      </li>
      <!-- x 10 -->
    </ul>

    <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
    <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
  </div>
</web-component-shadow-root>
```

```js
componentDidLoad() {
  UIkit.slider(this.sliderEl, {
    finite: true,
    sets: true
  });
}
```

Using the debugger, I can step into the `UIkit.slider` call so I know it is being invoked, but while the result *looks* correct, it has none of the expected functionality.  Indeed, it looks the same whether I call `UIkit.slider` or not.  Is it possible to use UIkit in a Shadow DOM context?

Comment: Check in F12 - Event Listeners Tab if the 6 EventListeners are set on ``<div uk-slider>``

Comment: It looks like no: https://imgur.com/a/x1L4Eqg

Comment: Then UIKit fails, raise an issue: https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues